# How to loop through each row of pySpark DataFrames and write back to Hive

Tags: python, api, optimization, pyspark, hive

I have some python code for hitting an API with records from a Hive Table and writing back to Hive as a new table with the additional columns from the API. I have a solution that works but unfortunately it is not scalable because of how long it takes.

I think the issue is that I am using collect to loop over the hive table pulled in via Spark. I saw that to take advantage of Spark's parallel computation framework, you could define a custom function and use map but when I try that I get an error that I cannot use SQL Context within the map function. I am hoping someone can point me to the correct way to do this or at least a better way. Any feedback is appreciated, thank you!

Steps in the code below:

Pull in input table from Hive as Spark DataFrame

For each row in the DataFrame:

1. Generate an xml request with the row data
2. Hit the API, receive and parse xml response
3. Create a dictionary with input and output values
4. Create Panda DataFrame from the dictionary
5. Create Spark DataFrame from the Pandas DataFrame
6. Write to CSV file in an HDFS directory that a Hive Table is built on

```
ResultsSpark = spark.sql("""select * from my_input_table""")

for row in ResultsSpark.collect():

    input = row.input

    data = []
    cols = []
    
    data.append(input)
    cols.append("input")
        
    body = """<request>""" + input + """</request>"""
    
    response = requests.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)
    
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

    
    
    ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('responseurl')
    ns.prefix = "ns1"
    ldoc = etree.parse(BytesIO(response.content))
    
    for sub_elements in ldoc.xpath('.//ns1:responseurl'):
        for element in sub_elements:
            data.append(element.text)
            cols.append(element.tag)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data).T  # Write in DF and transpose it
    df.columns = cols  # Update column names
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("responseurl", "")
    
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("input",StringType(),True), 
        StructField("output", StringType(), True) \
    ])
    df_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=schema)

    df_sdf.write.option("delimiter","^").save('hdfslocation', format='csv', mode='append')
```